# How to find difference between two dates in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying out a flutter application which can calculate the difference between two dates and display it in days.

But for some reason, I couldn't get the logic correct. I created enough variables to hold the current date and another variable to hold the old date, But still, I'm missing something.

I used [FLutter_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker) package.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentDate = DateTime.now();
    final oldDate = DateTime.tryParse();
    final difference = currentDate.difference(oldDate).inDays;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("data"),
                onPressed: () => DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                        showTitleActions: true,
                        currentTime: currentDate,
                        minTime: DateTime(1990, 1, 1), onConfirm: (date) {
                      setState(() {
                        date = oldDate;
                      });
                      print(difference);
                    })),
          ),
          Text(difference.toString())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the difference when you select new date in `onConfirm` method like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
  String difference = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("data"),
              onPressed: () => DatePicker.showDatePicker(
                context,
                showTitleActions: true,
                currentTime: currentDate,
                minTime: DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
                onConfirm: (date) {
                  setState(() {
                    difference = "${currentDate.difference(date).inDays}";
                  });
                  print(difference);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(difference),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put the variables outside of the `build()` method, because when you call `setState()` the `build()` method is called again.

You could initialize variables inside the `initState()` method, or in this case, you could just declare them with initialization.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.now();
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1));
Future<int> getDifference(DateTime date1,DateTime date2) async {
    print('date1 $date1');
    print('date2 $date2');
    print("${date1.difference(date2).inHours}");
    return date1.difference(date2).inHours;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.